# Using "marg" in a function - how to enquote correctly?

Tags: r, regression

Imagine I have a regression like:

```
regression <- glm(mpg ~ am * hp, data = mtcars)
```

I can easily calculate marginal effects with the `modmarg` package:

```
library(modmarg)
margins <- marg(
    regression, var_interest = "am",
    at = list("hp" = 52:110),
    type = "effects")
```

However, I have many models with different variables to compute margins for, so I'd like to put this into a function:

```
plotting_marg <- function(reg, cov) {
  margins <- marg(
    reg, var_interest = "truth",
    at = list(cov = 52:110),
    type = "effects") 
}
plotting_marg(regression, "hp", -3, 3)
```

```
Error in .marg(mod = mod, var_interest = var_interest, data = data, weights = weights,  : 
  var_interest %in% names(data) is not TRUE
```

This does not work, presumably because `cov` is not correctly enquoted. I have played around with `enquo`, but no luck. What is the way to go here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming the `list` with an object passed can be done with `setNames`

```
plotting_marg <- function(reg, cov) {
  marg(
    reg, var_interest = "am",
    at = setNames(list(52:110), cov),
    type = "effects") 
}
```

-testing

```
> plotting_marg(regression, "hp")
$`hp = 52`
   Label   Margin Standard.Error Test.Stat    P.Value Lower CI (95%) Upper CI (95%)
1 am = 0 0.000000       0.000000       NaN        NaN       0.000000       0.000000
2 am = 1 5.238604       1.918006  2.731276 0.01079466       1.309746       9.167462

$`hp = 53`
   Label   Margin Standard.Error Test.Stat    P.Value Lower CI (95%) Upper CI (95%)
1 am = 0 0.000000       0.000000       NaN        NaN       0.000000       0.000000
2 am = 1 5.239007       1.904537  2.750803 0.01030278       1.337739       9.140274

$`hp = 54`
   Label   Margin Standard.Error Test.Stat     P.Value Lower CI (95%) Upper CI (95%)
1 am = 0 0.000000       0.000000       NaN         NaN       0.000000       0.000000
2 am = 1 5.239409       1.891116  2.770539 0.009827057       1.365635       9.113184
...
```

---

Or may require `lst` from `dplyr/purrr`

```
plotting_marg <- function(reg, cov) {
  marg(
    reg, var_interest = "am",
    at = dplyr::lst(!!cov := 52:110),
    type = "effects") 
}
```

-testing

```
> plotting_marg(regression, "hp")
$`hp = 52`
   Label   Margin Standard.Error Test.Stat    P.Value Lower CI (95%) Upper CI (95%)
1 am = 0 0.000000       0.000000       NaN        NaN       0.000000       0.000000
2 am = 1 5.238604       1.918006  2.731276 0.01079466       1.309746       9.167462

$`hp = 53`
   Label   Margin Standard.Error Test.Stat    P.Value Lower CI (95%) Upper CI (95%)
1 am = 0 0.000000       0.000000       NaN        NaN       0.000000       0.000000
2 am = 1 5.239007       1.904537  2.750803 0.01030278       1.337739       9.140274

$`hp = 54`
   Label   Margin Standard.Error Test.Stat     P.Value Lower CI (95%) Upper CI (95%)
1 am = 0 0.000000       0.000000       NaN         NaN       0.000000       0.000000
2 am = 1 5.239409       1.891116  2.770539 0.009827057       1.365635       9.113184
...
```